# Find word and replace word after that in string using c#

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I have a string such that:

```
string values = .....href="http://mynewsite.humbler.com.........href="http://mynewsite.anticipate.com..... and so on
```

I need to find "mynewsite: keyword and then to replace "com" with "net".
There are many "com" present in the string so I couldn't simply use values.Replace method.
Also, there are many other sites presents besides "mysite", so I couldn't search on the basis of http...

Comment: May we have a look at your actual code?

Comment: In your string do you have string like `mynewsite.humbler.com` and do you want to append them with `net` as well

Comment: no I just want to replace com with net, and your code worked fine for me.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=http:\/\/mynewsite\.)(\w+\.)com
```

Try this.Replace by `$1net`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/26

Comment: It doesn't work for `mynewsite.humbler-with-dash.com`

Comment: @M42 have asked clarification to OP regarding the same

Answer (score 0):

Since C# regex supports quantifiers inside lookbehinds, you could try the below regex. Then replace the matched `.com` with `.net`

```
@"(?<=(https?://)?(www\.)?(\S+?\.)?mynewsite(\.\S+?)?)\.com"
```

**Example:**

```
string str = @"....href=""http://mynewsite.humbler.com"" href=""www.foo.mynewsite.humbler.com"" foo bar href=""http://mynewsite.anticipate.com"" ";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=(https?://)?(www\.)?(\S+?\.)?mynewsite(\.\S+?)?)\.com", ".net");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
....href="http://mynewsite.humbler.net" href="www.foo.mynewsite.humbler.net" foo bar href="http://mynewsite.anticipate.net"
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/85kr4m)